# How to read meta property of a document using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, meta

I am using AngularJS 1.6.3. I need to read meta properties of the Html document inside and AngularJS service.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="keys" content="key1, key2"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Does AngularJS provide something like `CookieService ($cookies)` for Meta tags?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any core service that implements what you are looking for. You will need to use the `$document` service and look for the meta tags you want. Something like this should work:

`$document.head.querySelectorAll('meta')`

Then loop over the items and find the one you are looking for.